# Assigning a date in dateTimeArray results in an Error when ComboBox is selected

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to select an item in combobox, each item i must assign a date through dateTimePicker, which then save in arrayDateTime. But when i select a combobox, it says that arrayDateTime is not an empty/null.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    DateTimePicker dateTimeSelection = new DateTimePicker();

    DateTime[] arrayDateTime = new DateTime[10];

    ComboBox comboBoxDates = new ComboBox();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dateTimeSelection.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimeSelection.CustomFormat = "MMMM/dd/yyyy";
        dateTimeSelection.MinDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        dateTimeSelection.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        Controls.Add(dateTimeSelection);
        dateTimeSelection.ValueChanged += DateTimePicker_dateTimeSelectionValueChanged;
        dateTimeSelection.Location = new Point(10, 40);

        Controls.Add(comboBoxDates);
        comboBoxDates.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_comboBoxDatesSelectedIndexChanged;
        comboBoxDates.Location = new Point(10, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        { comboBoxDates.Items.Add(i + "-Dates"); }
    }

    private void DateTimePicker_dateTimeSelectionValueChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        arrayDateTime[comboBoxDates.SelectedIndex] = dateTimeSelection.Value;
    }

    private void ComboBox_comboBoxDatesSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(arrayDateTime[comboBoxDates.SelectedIndex]!=null)
        {arrayDateTime[comboBoxDates.SelectedIndex] = dateTimeSelection.Value;}
    }
}
}
```

what i want to accomplish is, i will assign a date in each combobox item via datetimearray through selecting a date in datetimepicker.

Comment: I think I am not able to understand your question correctly

Comment: i edited the code and it works, but the value that i assign in combobox is not showing. I assign 0-Dates=October 1, 2016,1-Dates=October 2, 2016. When i select 0-Dates again, datetimepicker is not updating its calendar date, it must show October 1, 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yor are checking the `arrayDateTime[comboBoxDates.SelectedIndex]` should not be equal to `null` whereas it have the value of `1/1/0001 12:00:00` at the time of initalization. Thus I have initalized a blank DateTime dt variable without any value so it also have `1/1/0001` and thus it doesnot match if the `arrayDateTime` index has not be given a new date from datepicker.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
if(arrayDateTime[comboBoxDates.SelectedIndex] != dt)
{
    dateTimeSelection.Value = arrayDateTime[comboBoxDates.SelectedIndex];
}
```

Hope this helps